# List/links with images

Tags: html, list, image

So I'm developing a sort of simple web, with a navigation list and I would like to have images as part of the list parts. Something like youtube has with it's lists

It just doesn't seem to work for me, I tried looking it up on w3schools but either I'm missing it or I just can't find it there. The only thing I found was either to make the whole li \li as a part of div with the image inside of the div, or to place the image over the list, either way I can't really make it work, any tips here ?

Comment: Could you include what you have done so far, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the images inside the list items. Here I'll show you the code for navigation bar with dummy image names.

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href=""> <img src="home.png" alt="Home"> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> <img src="trending.png" alt="Trending"> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> <img src="subscriptions.png" alt="Subscriptions"> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> <img src="library.png" alt="Library"> </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

All you have to do is put the images inside the **anchor** tags and put the anchor tags inside **list** tags respectively.

If this answer solves your problem or helps you solve your problem, consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the **tick** on the left hand side.

Comment: Hi, I tried it asap, and it is working. I was probably just using this method the wrong way. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I'm happy to help.